# Vigenere Encription with different mod

Tags: c++, encryption

I've been trying to write a C++ program which can encrypt the given letters into Vigenere-encrypted ones. It works if the alphabet is 26-letters long but when I try to make them work with different sized alphabet (lets say 25 for this example), I get irrelevant codes.

For example:

> ALPHABET: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY (alphabet length is 25)
>   TEXT : MUADGRATRYINGTOMAKEITWORK
>   KEY: KAIJG
>   ENCRYPTEDTEXT: CANRRHFHGKXSTIACFXSTJCCGV
>   DECRYPTEDTEXT: RAFILWFYWENSLYTRFPJNYCTWP

My current formula is for encryption is:

```
    for (i = 0; i < lengthoftext; i++) {

        encryptedtext[i] = ((text[i] + keytext[i]) % alphabetlength) + 'A' + 1;
        if (encryptedtext[i] < 65) {
            encryptedtext[i] = encryptedtext[i] + alphabetlength;
        }
        if (encryptedtext[i] > 90) {
            encryptedtext[i] -= alphabetlength;
        }
```

And formula for decryption is:

```
    for (i = 0; i < lengthoftext; i++) {
          decryptedtext[i] = (((decryptedtext[i] - keytext[i]) + alphabetlength) % alphabetlength) + 'A' - 1 - (5 * (26 - alphabetlength));
        if (decryptedtext[i] < 65) {
            decryptedtext[i] = decryptedtext[i] + alphabetlength;
        }

        if (decryptedtext[i] > 90)
            decryptedtext[i] = decryptedtext[i] - alphabetlength;
    }
```

So, it works for mod 26 with no problems but when I try to change my alphabet into, lets say, ABCDEFGH and then try to return it to its decrypted form, I get irrelevant results. I couldn't find any pattern while changing the length of alphabet. I'd like to know how to change my formulas or a new way to do the encrytion.

Comment: `keytext[i]` should be `keytext[i % len(key) ]`

Comment: Or he could've repeated it as many times as needed in the code before that, we don't know...

Comment: nothing has changed. result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyse what's going on with your code here for the first letter 'M' for example.

I'll replace it in your first line of code. *By the way, I suppose that `keyText` contains a repetition of your keyword as many times as needed in order to contain the same number of characters as your example : `KAIJGKAIJGKAIJGKA...`.*

`encryptedtext[i] = ((text[i] + keytext[i]) % alphabetlength) + 'A' + 1;`

This would look something like this :

`encryptedtext[i] = (('M' + 'K')% 25) + 'A' + 1`

By replacing values with the [ascii table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) you get :

`encryptedtext[i] = ((77 + 75)% 25) + 65 + 1` which means `encryptedtext[i] = 67`

Which is indeed C.

**In summary** : ASCII has a 26 character alphabet table, which is possibly not the same as your own `alphabetlength`. Create your own alphabet map, do not rely on ASCII to int translations, that's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Yes, keyText is repetition of my keyword. Sorry for not pointing it out. I thought about creating my own alphabet map but wanted a short cut too but if there isn't any, then i have to do it...